# Adding user to a orphned Folder in window server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a window 2003 server, I have the administrator privileges as well. I have a folder, in this folder on security Tab I have removed all the user including owner , admin etc. and now this folder, I am unable give add any user, also I am unable to delete or copy this folder. Please suggest any solution. Ho I can add owner, user to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the advanced security on the folder and take ownership/re-assign ownership.  Then you should be able to reassign regular permissions (you may have to completely close out of the dialog and go back in, but that should do the trick).